How can I debug this code regarding installation of packages
I am new to the application of Rstudio and have been facing issues regarding the installation of certain package. How am I supposed to rectify this issue ? -
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6:
  cannot open URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/PACKAGES'
Packages which are only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘xts’ ‘zoo’
  ‘TTR’
  These will not be installed
> install.packages("lattice")
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘lattice’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6:
  cannot open URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/PACKAGES'
> install.packages("zoo")
Warning in install.packages :
  dependency ‘lattice’ is not available
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6:
  cannot open URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/PACKAGES'
Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘zoo’
  These will not be installed

I am trying to add packages to start a monte carlo simulation but cant apply the packages necessary for it.

The easiest solution is to install a current version of R. v3.6.1 is from 2019.

The obvious advice first: Update your R installation, 3.6 is 5 years old. Secondly, most packages have minimum requirements (around >= R 3.6), which means they should theoretically install from source, but that's not guaranteed. Any dependency that requires a more recent version will break the whole installation process. Btw, package ‘lattice’ is not available most likely means you're not installing from source.
